# SQLITE executing query failed

Tags: php, sql, database, sqlite, database-connection

I have made a db file using sqlite db browser and added tables too but it showing this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: user...

```
class Database {
    
        public $conn;
    
        public function __construct() {
    
            try {
    
                $this->conn = new PDO('sqlite: posDB.db');
                $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                return $this->conn;
    
            } catch (PDOException $e){
                
                echo "Connection failed" . $e->getMessage();
    
            }
        }
    }

$database = new Database();
```

This is my query:

```
$database->conn->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = $id LIMIT 1");
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant `sqlite:posDB.db`, not `sqlite: posDB.db` (note the space). The latter creates a *new* db file named `' posDB.db'` the first time your run it, and since it doesn't have any tables, your query fails.

Comment: I used sqlite:posDB.db , but giving out the same error even the table exists

Comment: Try providing absolute path to the db file in your connection string then. When using just the filename, PHP assumes the file's located in its current working directory (which may or may not be the same as the script's location).